# List Chat messages for a user in MS Teams throws forbidden error - Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using GraphAPI to list all the chats for a user in MS Teams using '/users/{Id}/chats' API. I have given Delegated permission type for both Chat.Read and Chat.ReadWrite. Still I am getting 403 forbidden error. Any help?

Comment: Have you granted admin consent for the API permissions?

Comment: But it says for Chat.Read and Chat.ReadWrite admin consent not required. I do not see any option on azure portal to grant admin consent for these methods. Can you please help?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis "List chats using application permissions doesn't exist, with or without protected API access"

You will need admin consent I believe